# Variable used within its own initial value while variable is used inside a closure past init

Tags: swift, swift2

```
typealias CBType = () -> Void

class A {

    let b = B()

    func test() {
        let token = b.register { CBType in
            self.b.waitFor([token]) // ERROR: Variable used within its own initial value
        }

        b.dispatch()
    }
}

class B {
    private var _callbacks = [String:CBType]()

    func register(callback: CBType) -> String {
        let id = "1234"
        _callbacks[id] = callback
        return id
    }

    func dispatch() {
        for (_, cb) in self._callbacks {
            cb()
        }
    }

    func waitFor(tokens: [String]) {
    }
}

A().test()
```

When I modify the test function to use a instance variable, things are working again but that syntax feels a bit heavy.

```
class A {

    let b = B()
    var token: String?

    func test() {
        token = b.register { CBType in
            self.b.waitFor([self.token!])
        }

        b.dispatch()
    }
}
```

Why can't I use a local variable in the closure since it will be way past initialization when the closure is finally called?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The constant `token` doesn't have a value at the time it is captured by the closure.

You can use a mutable variable instead, and the closure will capture the variable rather the its value.

```
func test() {
    var token = ""
    token = b.register {
        self.b.waitFor([token])
    }

    b.dispatch()
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass the token as a parameter into the closure:

```
typealias CBType = (String) -> Void

class A {
    let b = B()

    func test() {
        let token = b.register { theToken in
            self.b.waitFor([theToken])
        }

        b.dispatch()
    }
}

class B {
    private var _callbacks = [String:CBType]()

    func register(callback: CBType) -> String {
        let id = "1234"
        _callbacks[id] = callback
        return id
    }

    func dispatch() {
        for (id, cb) in self._callbacks {
            cb(id)
        }
    }

    func waitFor(tokens: [String]) {
        println("Wait for \(tokens)")
    }
}

A().test()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, `token` doesn't have a value when you make the call `self.b.waitFor([token])`.

In your second example, everything appears to work because by declaring `token` like so: `var token: String?` it is given an initial value (`nil`).

The issue isn't whether you are using an instance variable -vs- a local variable (or that it's being used within a closure), the issue is that (in the first example) you are trying to use the `token` within the expression that provides its initial value.

Equivalent to this would be declaring an `Int` like so: `let myValue: Int = myValue + 1` - its initial value is supposed to be "what" + 1?

Comment: I realize this but I am still confused by the fact that a closure is just a function pointer: the function code isn't ran till the closure is invoked. So why is the compiler insisting as to initializing the variable if the same variable isn't referenced till the closure code is executed?

Comment: the compiler is doing its job  :)  there is no possible condition under which `token` can be successfully initialized, hence the error re: referring to itself while setting its initial value - I'm grateful that it's smart enough to give me these kinds of errors!

Comment: @JohnDifool your hunch is correct. There is no problem here and this works in other languages like Haskell and is called "tying the knot".  This is a swift deficiency.